# Change the background-color on a button after clicking

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i write on a rating button and i wanted to change the background color from the button after i clicked it but my code does nothing.

```
    <ul>
         <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">1</p></button></li>
         <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">2</p></button></li>
         <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">3</p></button></li>
         <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">4</p></button></li>
         <li><button class="btn"><p id="num">5</p></button></li>

       </ul>
          
-----


const btn = document.querySelector('.btn'); 

 btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick(){
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'; 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');` is only targeting the first button.

You need to use querySelectorAll to select all buttons and add event listeners to each of them.

```js
const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn'); 

allBtns.forEach(btn => {
   btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick(){
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'; 
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
const btnList = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

   btnList.forEach(btn => {
     btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick() {
     btn.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're selecting multiple buttons from DOM you've to `querySelectorAll` and then you need to loop over it to get your desired output

```
    const btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn'); 
    btn.forEach(b => {
      b.addEventListener('click', function onClick(){
        b.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'; 
     });  
    })
```